# Linux : How can the sed command filter all fields except first and last?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

i am trying to make this script that filters a line coming from ps..
the script it almost done, only this line missing.

for example,here's a line i need to filter :

```
803 ?   (many spaces here)   00:00:00 atd
```

i need this like to look like this :

```
803 atd
```

i've tried everything but it seems that a simple sed argument can't do this.. if sed detects something that has to be erased, it deletes the whole line after it..
please correct me if i am wrong and thanks for your time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command for sed:

```
sed 's/ .* / /'
```

It takes the first space, as much as possible, then the last space, and replaces them with a single space.

If you can have spaces at the beginning or the end of the string, then you need to be a little more careful with your sed command.  It's not nearly as elegant here:

```
sed 's/^ *\([^ ]\+\).*  *\([^ ]\+\) *$/\1 \2/'
```

This captures non-space characters and puts them in the output stream.  Without an extended sed like GNU sed, you need to replace the occurrences of `[^ ]\+` with `[^ ][^ ]*`.

That being said, `awk` is clearly the most graceful tool for this job.

Comment: Just think about spaces in the beginning and in the end of line. `echo " 803 atd " | sed 's/ .* / /'` for example.

Comment: Do you want to preserve those spaces or not?

Comment: If you're using GNU sed, how about `s/\> .* \</ /` or `s/\b .* \b/ /`?

Comment: @potong: Those don't strip leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I thought you wanted to preserve the spaces.

Comment: No, I think he didn't want to keep those.

Comment: i have to use sed and not awk.. :(
this one really works anyway, and thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you're looking for a `awk`.

`awk '{print $1 " " $NF}'` print 1st field and last field of every input line. `NF` is actually a number of fields.

```
$> echo "803 ? (many spaces here) 00:00:00 atd" | awk '{print $1 " " $NF}'
803 atd
```

Comment: Nice, better than my poor `awk` suggestion; Dmitrij's grabs the last field, explicitly, regardless of the number of fields.

Comment: Short and simple … +1 (though `awk '{print $1,$NF}'` would be just fine) :)

Answer (score 2):

actually, you can do this perhaps more easily with perl or awk, …

```
    perl -ane 'print "$F[0] $F[-1]\n"' # first and last field

    awk '{print $1 " " $6}'            # first and sixth field
```